# Need to update custom option value in shopping cart page

Tags: magento

I have a small problem with my shopping cart page.

In my shopping cart have these fields.

- Quantity
- Product description. (like **1 product $27**)

My problem is,

If, I update the  the quantity of my shopping cart item. For example, I will update 1 quantity as 3 quantity. And need to change the product description also. From **1 product $27** to **3 product $81**.

**This my sample code:**

```
<?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>

            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>            

            <?php //if($ii > 2) { ?>

            <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>

            <dd style="padding-left:0px;" <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>>

            <?php $license_val = $_formatedOptionValue['value']; ?>
```

I get the option value from backend by using this **$_formatedOptionValue['full_view']**. So only, I much confused.

Now, I am using custom option for the product description. I need to update the custom option value. Is there any possible? Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What you already tried?  Put some code.

Comment: You want change the core codes or make custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it much simpeler to retrieve the qty and the subtotal and echo these values in a translate string, you already have the data after the update for the items.

```
$this->__('%s product %s', $qty, $subtotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple just override your checkout controller and then edit updateCheckoutPost function for update custom option value, with price.

```
Add this code only in updateCheckoutPost function 100% working.

you need cart items id's, item's product id, qty or options array of particular product.

foreach($_POST['item_ids'] as $update_product_id){
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_POST['product_ids'][$update_product_id][0]); 
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
                $cart->init();
                $params = array(
                'product' => $_POST['product_ids'][$update_product_id][0],
                'qty' => $_POST['cart'][$update_product_id]['qty'],
                'options' => $_POST['option'][$update_product_id]);
                $cart->updateItem($update_product_id,$params);
                $cart->save();
           }
```